# How to search for a type of business in a particular area that is open at a particular time of day

Tags: google-search, google-maps

I've recently discovered that it's possible to find businesses that are "open now" using a Google search query that passes the "tbm=lcl" parameter, e.g. `https://www.google.com/search?tbm=lcl&ei=eKwTWu2xCILVafeHoYAD&q=restaurant%20hours%20near%20asheville%20nc`.

These queries can be constructed by searching, for example, `restaurant hours near asheville nc` in the main Google search box, then clicking "More places", then selecting "Open now" in the Hours dropdown menu.

However, this functionality is somewhat limited as it doesn't allow one to search for restaurants that *will* be open when one is hungry in the middle of the night before it is the middle of the night when there may not be any restaurants open.

Somewhat counter-intuitively, this interface appears to be distinct from Google Maps, a rather more obvious place one would look for such functionality.

Is there an interface to Google's database that provides the ability to locate a business open at a particular time of day providing a particular service?

Comment: I haven't tested this, but it might be worth a try: search in google maps *at the target time of day* along with something along the lines of *open now*.

Answer (score 1):

On Google Search, if you search for food, let say pizza, for restaurant or something like these, the results page shows a map and below it an **Hours** dropdown menu where you could select the day, and after that you could select the time.

[image]

Comment: @pnuts Have you hear about [Google Local Guides](https://maps.google.com/localguides)?